# CSS position:absolute but html order still matters

Tags: html, css

I have a web page with an equivalent of the following html, and the corresponding CSS:

```
<div class="father">
    <div class="divson"></div>
    <a class="ason"></a>
</div>

.father     {position:relative}
.father div {position:absolute}
.father a   {position:relative}
```

Because 'divson' has position:absolute, I'd expect it to be always placed relatively to 'father' (because this one is positioned as well). Although, 'divson' still moves elsewhere when I reorder the html as follows:

```
<div class="father">
    <a class="ason"></a>
    <div class="divson"></div>
</div>
```

How is it possible that a div with position:absolute still depends on the html order? What could be a cause that I wouldn't have thought of?

Thanks

Comment: “Moves elsewhere” certainly when no `top` and `left` is given. On `divson`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have not set the left, top, bottom, right property for the divson. You have to set these to fix your div position, if you are using absolute positioning.

```
.divson{
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0
}
```

Comment: I gotta make a couple checks, but this seems to work! I thought those values were default.. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

As [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) says:

```
position: absolute;
```

The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element.

Comment: Right, but the ancestor 'father' is not static tho, it is positioned as well with position:relative

Comment: That's the point actually

Answer (score 0):

Display: flex
and play with items order (order:1; order:2;)

Comment: Thanks for the consideration. Check out the answer. `:)`